# C strtok() split string into tokens but keep old data unaltered

Tags: c, strtok

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char str[] = "John|Doe|Melbourne|6270|AU";

    char fname[32], lname[32], city[32], zip[32], country[32];
    char *oldstr = str;

    strcpy(fname, strtok(str, "|"));
    strcpy(lname, strtok(NULL, "|"));
    strcpy(city, strtok(NULL, "|"));
    strcpy(zip, strtok(NULL, "|"));
    strcpy(country, strtok(NULL, "|"));

    printf("Firstname: %s\n", fname);
    printf("Lastname: %s\n", lname);
    printf("City: %s\n", city);
    printf("Zip: %s\n", zip);
    printf("Country: %s\n", country);
    printf("STR: %s\n", str);
    printf("OLDSTR: %s\n", oldstr);

    return 0;
}
```

Execution output:

```
$ ./str
Firstname: John
Lastname: Doe
City: Melbourne
Zip: 6270
Country: AU
STR: John
OLDSTR: John
```

Why can't I keep the old data nor in the `str` or `oldstr`, what am I doing wrong and how can I not alter the data or keep it?

Comment: xtmtrx [here in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847194/linked-list-data-all-the-same/15847214#15847214) I written a code that shows how `strtok()` works (it modify string in same address space), I think you should have a look:

Comment: I would expect one to read the source code to the strtok() function or read the function documentation before asking such a question.

Comment: So here is [the source code of strkok()](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-166/string.subproj/strtok.c)

Comment: Either make a copy of `str` before you call `strtok` or don't use `strtok` and use a pair of pointers to bracket and copy each token, or a combination of `strcspn` and `strspn` to do the same thing. With either of the other methods you can tokenize a string-literal because the original isn't modified, but `strtok` modifies the original by replacing the separator with nul-characters.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

when you do `strtok(NULL, "|")` `strtok()` find token and put `null` on place (*replace token with `\0`*) and modify string.

you `str`, becomes:

```
char str[] = John0Doe0Melbourne062700AU;
                 
  Str array in memory 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|'J'|'o'|'h'|'n'|0|'D'|'o'|'e'|0|'M'|'e'|'l'|'b'|'o'|'u'|'r'|'n'|'e'|0|'6'|'2'|'7'|'0'|0|'A'|'U'|0|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                 ^  replace | with \0  (ASCII value is 0)
```

*Consider the diagram is important because char `'0'` and `0` are diffident (in string 6270 are char in figure parenthesised by `'` where for `\0` 0 is as number)*

when you print str using `%s` it print chars upto first `\0` that is `John`

To keep your original str unchanged you should fist copy str into some tempstr variable and then use that `tempstr` string in `strtok()`:

```
char str[] = "John|Doe|Melbourne|6270|AU";
char* tempstr = calloc(strlen(str)+1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(tempstr, str);
```

Now use this `tempstr` string in place of str in your code.

Comment: A well compiled answer +1 :)

Comment: You could replace `calloc + strcpy` with a simple `strdup`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `oldstr` is just a pointer, an assignment will not make a new copy of your string.

Copy it before passing str to the `strtok`:

```
          char *oldstr=malloc(sizeof(str));
          strcpy(oldstr,str);
```

Your corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main (void) {

   char str[] = "John|Doe|Melbourne|6270|AU";
   char fname[32], lname[32], city[32], zip[32], country[32];
   char *oldstr = malloc(sizeof(str));
   strcpy(oldstr,str);

    ...................
    free(oldstr);
return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @CodeClown mentioned, in your case, it's better to use `strncpy`. And instead of fixing the sizes of `fname` etc before hand, you can have pointers in their place and allocate the memory as is required not more and not less. That way you can avoid writing to the buffer out of bounds......

Another Idea: 
   would be to assign the result of `strtok` to pointers `*fname`, `*lname`, etc.. instead of arrays. It seems the `strtok` is designed to be used that way after seeing the accepted answer.

Caution:In this way, if you change `str` further that would be reflected in `fname`,`lname` also. Because, they just point to `str` data but not to new memory blocks. So, use `oldstr` for other manipulations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main (void) {

    char str[] = "John|Doe|Melbourne|6270|AU";
    char *fname, *lname, *city, *zip, *country;
    char *oldstr = malloc(sizeof(str));
    strcpy(oldstr,str);
    fname=strtok(str,"|");
    lname=strtok(NULL,"|");
    city=strtok(NULL, "|");
    zip=strtok(NULL, "|");
    country=strtok(NULL, "|");

    printf("Firstname: %s\n", fname);
    printf("Lastname: %s\n", lname);
    printf("City: %s\n", city);
    printf("Zip: %s\n", zip);
    printf("Country: %s\n", country);
    printf("STR: %s\n", str);
    printf("OLDSTR: %s\n", oldstr);
    free(oldstr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer! Maybe use `strncpy()` and do not use static buffers as some people or cities have names longer than 32 characters. His next question will be about stack corruption :-)

Comment: In a real program - rather than just something lashed up to ask a question about - don't forget to `free` the memory used by `oldstr` when you've done.

Comment: @Code Clown, yes, stack corruption :P solved with Grijesh Chauhan answer

Comment: Yes, I do `free(str)` and `free(oldstr)`

Comment: @pinkpanther here is not, but in the working code my `str` is dynamically allocated (Curl data from web).

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` requires an writeable input string and it modifies the input string. If you want to keep the input string you have to a make a copy of it first.

For example:

```
char str[] = "John|Doe|Melbourne|6270|AU";
char oldstr[32];

strcpy(oldstr, str);  // Use strncpy if you don't know
                      // the size of str
```

Comment: Better get the length of the string first and create a fitting data as people have different names and live in different cities.

Answer (score 0):

You just copy the pointer to the string, but not the string itself. Use `strncpy()` to create a copy.

```
char *oldstr = str; // just copy of the address not the string itself!
```

Comment: this does not prevent strtok() from changing the contents of the string.

Comment: @EugeneBujak True, but only in the copy. The original stays unchanged.

Comment: So why is the use of strcpy() not included in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `for()` loop below shows how code calls `strtok()` at only one location.

```
int separate( char *flds[], int size, char *fullStr ) {
    int count = 0;
    for( char *cp = fullStr; ( cp = strtok( cp, " " ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL ) {
        flds[ count ] = strdup( cp ); // must be free'd later!
        if( ++count == size )
            break;
    }
    return( count );
}
```