# String parsing in C using strtok

Tags: c, parsing, strtok, calloc

I've got this little source code, made for testing the parsing of a string similar to variable `string` I need to use in other project

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (void)
{
    char string[] = "C-AC-2C-3C-BOB";
    char* s;
    char* hand[3];
    char* usr;


    s = (char*) calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    hand[1] = (char*) calloc(3, sizeof(char));
    hand[2] = (char*) calloc(3, sizeof(char));
    hand[3] = (char*) calloc(3, sizeof(char));
    usr = (char*) calloc(21, sizeof(char));

    s = strtok (string,"-");
    hand[1] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    hand[2] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    hand[3] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    usr = strtok (NULL, "\0");

    printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", s, hand[1], hand[2], hand[3], usr);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that i got these `3C:AC:2C:3C:BOB` as result of printf instead of `C:AC:2C:3C:BOB`.

-------EDIT-----

Code without memory leaks. Problem remains

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (void)
{
    char string[] = "C-AC-2C-3C-BOB";
    char* s;
    char* hand[3];
    char* usr;

    s = strtok (string,"-");
    hand[1] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    hand[2] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    hand[3] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    usr = strtok (NULL, "\0");

    printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", s, hand[1], hand[2], hand[3], usr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have memory leaks in your programs. First you allocate memory and assign to a set of pointers, then you overwrite those pointers with the result from `strtok`.

Comment: Ok, editing the whole part of allocation with `calloc` doesn not resolve the main problem

Comment: @ArrigoPierotti remove all `calloc()` lines then  compile and run again

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan code edited, but problem remains

Comment: Arrays in C are `0`-base indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare an array `hand` as having three entries, then you index it using indexes `1` through `3`. But arrays in C have indexes from `0` to `size-1` (e.g. `2` in your case).

So you write/read to/from out of bounds of the array, leading to undefined behavior.

Change the indexes of your array to `0` through `2` and it should work fine.

Comment: Oh frack >_>
Didn't really noticed of this stupid error >_>
Program now works correctly, thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your code you have out-of index problem that causes Undefined behavior at runtime:

```
hand[3] = strtok (NULL, "-"); 
     ^

printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", s, hand[1], hand[2], hand[3], usr);
                                                     ^
                                                 wrong index value
```

Remember index value in array starts with `0` according to declaration `char* hand[3];` index values can be 0 to 2

Comment: Oh frack >_> Didn't really noticed of this stupid error >_> Program now works correctly, thanks

Comment: @ArrigoPierotti one more thing is that `strtok()` modifies the input string and replace all delimiters with `\0`

Comment: @ArrigoPierotti check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104953/c-strtok-split-string-into-tokens-but-keep-old-data-unaltered/17104999#17104999) What I mean to say if you ready to modify your string then just replace `-` with `:` in your original string

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (void)
{
    char string[] = "C-AC-2C-3C-BOB";
    char* s;
    char* hand[3];
    char* usr;

    s = strtok (string,"-");
    hand[0] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    hand[1] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    hand[2] = strtok (NULL, "-");
    usr = strtok (NULL, "\0");

    printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", s, hand[0], hand[1], hand[2], usr);

    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to `calloc` your pointers, since `strtok()` will return a valid memory address (actually `strtok()` modifies the string and replace the separator by an null char).
The other problem is the indexes of the array: in C, an index starts at 0. The first element of `hand` is `hand[0]` and the last one is `hand[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the stack of you program:

```
+-----------------------+
|       ...
|
|0x***00 hand[0]
|
|
|           
|0x***04 hand[1]       
|
|
|     
|0x***08 hand[2]           
|                  
|
|
|0x***0C hand[3]    
|                       <---hander[1] pointer this address    
|    
|______  hand[3] end here
```

So the hand[3] use the address the cover the *hand[1] , this is the `3C` come

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should annotation these lines to avoid memory leaks :

```
s = (char*) calloc(1, sizeof(char));
hand[1] = (char*) calloc(3, sizeof(char));
hand[2] = (char*) calloc(3, sizeof(char));
hand[3] = (char*) calloc(3, sizeof(char));
usr = (char*) calloc(21, sizeof(char));
```

Then, after change the code, I build and run the result in Windows and Linux, neither got your unexpected print result.