# Parsing issue in C

Tags: c, parsing, pattern-matching

I have a string in the format:

```
char *sampleLine = "name1: 251 name2: 23 name3: -67 name4: 0.00 name5: 310 name6: 410 name7: 54001 name8: 332 name9: SOME_TEXT name10: 3 name1: 181 235 237 name11: 11 name12: 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 name13: 0 name14: 2 name15: 1 name16: 0 name17: 6 name18: 0 name19: 500 name20: 200 name21: 64 name22: 1 name23: 6 name24: 0 name25: 0";
```

One of the issues with the string is that some of the names are repeated but the basic pattern seemed to be name: value. So I wrote an algorithm that would take a name and return a value but it doesn't seem to work and does not take into account the issue with a name being repeated.

So for example: if I pass in name1, I would expect to get 251 ,etc.

Here is the code with a sample main:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
#include <string.h>                                                             
#include <strings.h> 

char* extractValue(char* name, char* buffer)
{
    char* begining = strstr(buffer,name);
    begining += strlen(name) + 2;

    if (begining != NULL)
    {
        char* end = strstr(begining,":");

        if (end != NULL)
        {
            end += 1;

            for (int i=0; i < strlen(end); i++)
            {
                if (end[i] != ':')
                {
                    i++;
                } else {
                    char namevalue[200];
                    bzero(namevalue,200);

                    strncpy(namevalue,begining,i);

                    for (int x=strlen(namevalue); x>0; x--)
                    {
                        if (namevalue[x] == ' ')
                        {
                            char* value = (char*)malloc(200);
                            bzero(value,200);

                            strncpy(value,namevalue,strlen(namevalue) - (strlen(namevalue) - x));

                            return value;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    char *sampleLine = "name1: 251 name2: 23 name3: -67 name4: 0.00 name5: 310 name6: 410 name7: 54001 name8: 332 name9: SOME_TEXT name10: 3 name1: 181 235 237 name11: 11 name12: 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 name13: 0 name14: 2 name15: 1 name16: 0 name17: 6 name18: 0 name19: 500 name20: 200 name21: 64 name22: 1 name23: 6 name24: 0 name25: 0";

    char* value1  = extractValue("name1", sampleLine);
    char* value3  = extractValue("name3", sampleLine);
    char* value17 = extractValue("name17", sampleLine);

    printf("value 1 = %s\n",value1);
    printf("value 3 = %s\n",value3);
    printf("value 17 = %s\n",value17);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o parse parse.c && ./parse
value 1 = 251 name2: 23
value 3 = -67 name4: 0.00
value 17 = 6 name18: 0 name19: 500 name20: 200 name21:
```

Instead of expected

```
value 1 = 251
value 3 = -67
value 17 = 6
```

Comment: C or C++, which one? This looks like C.

Comment: It seems to be easier to implement in C++, but the question seems to be on C, so I won't answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two subtle errors.

First,

```
if (end[i] != ':')
{
   i++;
} else ..
```

By manually incrementing `i` here, you are skipping a character, as `i` already gets incremented by the for-loop. It *appears* to have no side effects, but only because ...

Second: the actual cause of your problem is you are measuring the length of the *wrong string*. You locate the beginning of the name value (`begining`) and then its `end` by scanning forward from that position for the next `:`. Then, you track backwards to find the previous space, which should be the end of the value. But ...

```
for (i=0; i < strlen(end); i++)
```

checks *forwards* from the (already determined) *end* of the string! Of course, for your test names, you are bound to find a colon somewhere further along--but its position has nothing to do with the string you are interested in, which is between `begining` and `end`.

Change your `i` loop to

```
for (i=0; i < end-begining; i++)
```

and change the `:` check to

```
if (begining[i] == ':')
{
   char namevalue[200];
   ... (etc.)
```

(discarding the `i++` line).

---

### Loose notes

A slightly faster way to look for a single character is `strchr`:

```
char* end = strchr(begining,':');
```

You might want to find a better strategy for locating the `name`. If you are looking for `name1`, it could find `name12` as well as `noname1`.

One way would be to split a string into tokens using `strtok`. Then anything ending with a `:` is a potential name, and the next token is the value you are looking for. Omitted, because it's a nice exercise in its own. (And if you are going to try this: [`strtok` modifies the original string!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104953/c-strtok-split-string-into-tokens-but-keep-old-data-unaltered))

Finally, you can do without all those loops :-)

```
char* extractValue(char* name, char* buffer)
{
    char *start, *end, *ret_val;
    int length;
    char* begining = strstr(buffer,name);
    if (!begining)
        return NULL;
    start = begining + strlen(name);
    if (start[0] != ':')
        return NULL;
    start++;

//  skip initial spaces, if any
    while (*start == ' ')
        start++;
//  ptr points to the start of data. Find end.
    end = start;
    while (*end && *end != ' ')
        end++;

//  we have the correct string in start..end
    length = end-start;

//  it's a zero-terminated string so add 1 for the zero
    ret_val = (char *)malloc(length+1);
    strncpy (ret_val, start, length);
//  put the zero where it belongs
    ret_val[length] = 0;

    return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: This works great for something like name2: 23 but doesn't work for the case where name12: 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 which only return 240. Any thoughts how to extract both types of values ?

Comment: In that case you can use your own idea: from `begining`, scan *forward* for the next `:`; if found, scan *backwards* again for a space. Change this where I update `end`, `start` is still good. A plus point, by the way, would be that if you have `nameX:` but no data it returns an empty string. My code returns the next name.